# How to update hive table metadata with latest AVRO schema file

Tags: hive, hdfs, bigdata, avro, hive-metastore

FAILED: RuntimeException MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException Encountered AvroSerdeException determining schema. Returning signal schema to indicate problem: Unable to read schema from given path: /master_data/XYZ/DA12195/business_date=20181126/_schema.avsc)

The schema file exists in new partition with business_date=20181129, but hive table is still pointing to schema file in older partition.

Comment: could you try `msck repair table <table_name>`

Comment: This doesn't help, since we have flushed the underlying data of AVRO table and then copied it back. In this case, Table metadata is incorrect.

Comment: what does this mean ` we have flushed the underlying data of AVRO table and then copied it back` did you delete data of whole table or should one partition?

Comment: We deleted AVRO data for the whole table, during testing phase. Now we have retrieve the dataset from Hadoop TRASH. But trying to query on the table, it fails with above error.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping external table and recreating it helped solve this problem.
Also MSCK REPAIR command helped recreating hive partitions.

File _schema.avsc file contain schema information about the AVRO table.We need to point hive table metadata to correct location of this file. serde and tblproperties needs to be updated for making this change